# Python Selenium copying text from div

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do you take the text "BURGUNDY" from the HTML code:

`<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>BURGUNDY</div>`

`<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>randomTxt</div>`

I can't figure it out, please help me by using Python or Selenium.
Thank You

Comment: Can you share the actual content of div as per your scraped data. Ideally using `div.text` you should be able to get the text content from any div element. Additional Information might help.

Answer (score 0):

First I don't know how much you familiar with selenium testing, I assume you have configured chrome driver or any web driver properly.

As I understand you want to read the inner content of a div tag.

With some easy steps, you can do that.

1. Get the element by id, class or XPath(you can find this using dev tools of the browser)
2. From that element, you can get the property innerHTML

ex: (note these codes are pseudo-codes, I don't remember exact syntaxes)

```
var element=driver.find_element_by_id('div_id');
var text=element.get_attribute('innerHTML');
```

Comment: is "innerHTML" a form of method or just a suggestion?

Comment: ```<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>BURGUNDY</div>```

```<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>randomTxt</div>```

Comment: to do this you have to go with the xpath. innerHTML is a method you can use it as just it is.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to selenium, I am on a new project requiring the code. How would you type the xpath? ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("col-md-12")```